# Identifying duplicate geometries in different layers with QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, geometry, duplication

I'm using QGIS 3.16 Hannover under MacOS 10.13 environment. I've got two polygon shapefile layers: `'LIC'` and `'ZEPA'`. Some polygons (name, code & geometry) are present in both layers and I want to identify them by adding a new field to the layer `'ZEPA'` with the value `"yes"` if that feature is also present in the other layer. I've tried in the field calculator the function `overlay_equals()`. My try has been

```
    array_to_string(overlay_equals('LIC', "yes"))
```

But it returns the new field empty (instead of `"yes"`) for those equal features. What is wrong?

Comment: Did you also try `'yes'`?

Comment: I did, but it returns NULL for all features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code actually does what I want:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN overlay_equals('LIC') = 1 THEN 'yes'
    ELSE NULL
END
```

Another option could be obtaining a 0/1 return, setting an integer field with the following expression:

```
overlay_equals('LIC')
```